# How can I learn reading Telugu texts, if I already know Kannada Scripts?

Tags: reading, writing-system, language-comparison

Is learning Telugu script need any extra effort if I already know reading Kannada script? since both languages are quite similar for reading.

Comment: For this question, do you just want to learn to read the [Telugu script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telugu_script) or also learn the [Telugu language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telugu_language)?

Comment: I am interested in learning Telugu Script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, learning Telugu script is a little bit of effort, but they are really similar. I would think you can learn it in less than a day.

Here is the basic [Kannada](http://www.ancientscripts.com/kannada.html) script, which is sounds like you already know:
[image]

And here is the basic [Telugu](http://www.ancientscripts.com/telugu.html) script, which you want to learn:
[image]

They are both [Dravidian languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dravidian_languages), and the similarities are everywhere in these scripts. The main differences appear to be: u, r gha, na, ta, śa. But even those letters have some similarities. Overall, it seems more like a matter of "getting used to" the Telugu script, as opposed to learning it from scratch, if you are already well versed in the Kannada script.

Comment: Good point about "getting used to" a slightly different script. I was able to do this when learning the Greek and Cyrillic alphabets through their strong similarity to the Roman alphabet, but I had to explicitly *learn* the Hebrew script through study and drilling. Yes, I know they are all related (from Proto-Semitic), but it's different enough in its modern form that I couldn't just pick up the gist as I went. Roman, Greek, and Cyrillic all come through Phoenecian, which was a sister script of Hebrew.